# What am i doing wrong here?

Tags: php

I've been staring at this page for over an hour. My update function just doesnt not seem to update. When i tried it through sql it seems ok. I have a form at the bottom of this page which updates a field in a table. Can anyone spot the mistakes?

```
   <?php

// First of all initialise the user and check for permissions
require_once "/var/www/users/user.php";
$user = new CHUser(2);


// Initialise the template
require_once "/var/www/template/template.php";
$template = new CHTemplate();

// And create a cid object
    require_once "/var/www/Testing/DisplayWIPOnLocation.php";
$BundleProgress= new CHWIPProgress();


 if(isset($_GET['Reference'])){

 $todays_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $content .= " <h3> Details for Bundle : $reference </h3> ";
 $bundle = $BundleProgress->GetBundle($_GET['Reference']);   
 $reference = $_GET['Reference'];

 // Now show the details

    foreach($bundle as $x){
        $content .= "
       <table>
                                     <tr>
                    <th> Location </th> 
                    <td>" . $x['Description'] . "</td> 
                    </tr>



                    <tr>
                    <th> Works Order Number </th> 
                    <td>" . $x['WorksOrder'] . "</td> 
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                    <th> Bundle Number </th> 
                            <td>" . $x['Number'] . "</td>
                    </tr>


                     <tr>
                    <th>Qty Issued</th>
                    <td>" . $x['Qty'] . "</td>

                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                    <th>Bundle Reference </th> 
                    <td>" . $x['Reference'] . "</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <th>Style description</th> 
                                            <td>" . $x['Stock'] . "</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                    <td>" . $x['DueDate'] . "</td>

                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                    <th>Date In </th>
                    <td>" . $x['DateIN'] . "</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <th>Date Out</th>
                    <td>" . $x['DateOUT'] . "</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <th>Last Code</th>
                    <td>" . $x['Last'] . "</td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

                <br> "; 

    }

                 $content .= " </table>
                <form action='viewBundle.php?step=2' method='post'>
                <p>Reason: <input type='text' name='reason' /><br       
                                    /><p>
                <p><input type='hidden' name='bundlereference'   
                                     id='Username' value='" . $x['Reference'] . "' />
                <input type='submit' name ='add'/></form>

                </table>  ";   

                if($_GET['step'] == 2) {



        $BundleProgress->UpdateReason($_POST['reason'],$_POST['bundlereference']);

                 $content .= " <a href='index.php?location=" .   
              $x['Description'] . "'> updated</a> "; 
                }

       }


     else {
    $content .= "<h3>Something has gone wrong</h3>

    <br>

    <a href='index.php?location=" . $x['Description'] . "'> Return to Previous            
  Page </a> 

    ";
}

  $template->SetTag("content", $content);
  echo $template->Display();

  ?>
```

Function

```
    public function UpdateReason($reason, $bundlereference) {
                    $sql = "UPDATE `ArchiveBundle`
                                    SET `Issue` = " . $reason . "
                                    WHERE `BundleReference` = " . $bundlereference .    
                ";";
                    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);
                    return mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
            }
```

Comment: "What am i doing wrong here?" "Not sanitizing user input  & trusting clients"

Comment: And failing to check the return calls of your database functions, so even you can't know what's going wrong...

Comment: Putting `<form>...</form>` between `</table>...</table>` !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
if($_GET['step'] == 2)
```

to:

```
if((int)$_GET['step'] === 2)
```

and:

```
public function UpdateReason($reason, $bundlereference) {
    $sql = "UPDATE `ArchiveBundle`
        SET `Issue` = " . $reason . "
        WHERE `BundleReference` = " . $bundlereference .    
        ";";
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);
    return mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
}
```

to:

```
public function UpdateReason($reason, $bundlereference) {
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);

    $_reason = mysql_real_escape_string($reason,$this->conn);
    $_bundlereference = mysql_real_escape_string($bundlereference,$this->conn);

    $sql = "UPDATE `ArchiveBundle`
            SET `Issue` = '" . $_reason . "'
            WHERE `BundleReference` = '" . $_bundlereference . "'";

    return mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
}
```

Try that. Code hasn't been tested but it's a good place to start.

To try and debug what's going on here do the following:

```
public function UpdateReason($reason, $bundlereference) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);

    if (!$db_selected) {
        die("Can't use db : " . mysql_error());
    }

    $_reason = mysql_real_escape_string($reason,$this->conn);
    $_bundlereference = mysql_real_escape_string($bundlereference,$this->conn);

    $sql = "UPDATE `ArchiveBundle`
            SET `Issue` = '" . $_reason . "'
            WHERE `BundleReference` = '" . $_bundlereference . "'";

    mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);

    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Also, it looks like on your form submission you're not passing in the Reference parameter so the if(isset($_GET['Reference'])) will fail when you post the form. I've change the table and form code below to make it more readable, pass in the Reference param on form submission, and also to update the db record BEFORE fetching the dataset so you'll see the updated records in the table returned.

```
// First of all initialise the user and check for permissions
require_once "/var/www/users/user.php";
$user = new CHUser(2);


// Initialise the template
require_once "/var/www/template/template.php";
$template = new CHTemplate();

// And create a cid object
require_once "/var/www/Testing/DisplayWIPOnLocation.php";
$BundleProgress= new CHWIPProgress();


if(isset($_GET['Reference'])){
    if($_GET['step'] == 2) {
        $BundleProgress->UpdateReason($_POST['reason'],$_POST['bundlereference']);
    }

    $todays_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $content .= " <h3> Details for Bundle : $reference </h3> ";
    $bundle = $BundleProgress->GetBundle($_GET['Reference']);   
    $reference = $_GET['Reference'];

    // Now show the details
    foreach($bundle as $x){
        $content .= "
                    <table>
                        <tr><th> Location </th><td>" . $x['Description'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th> Works Order Number </th><td>" . $x['WorksOrder'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th> Bundle Number </th><td>" . $x['Number'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Qty Issued</th><td>" . $x['Qty'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Bundle Reference </th><td>" . $x['Reference'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Style description</th><td>" . $x['Stock'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Due Date</th><td>" . $x['DueDate'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Date In </th><td>" . $x['DateIN'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Date Out</th><td>" . $x['DateOUT'] . "</td></tr>
                        <tr><th>Last Code</th><td>" . $x['Last'] . "</td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <br>";
    }

    $content .= "<table>
                    <form action='viewBundle.php?Reference=" . $_GET['Reference'] . "&step=2' method='post'>
                        <p>Reason: <input type='text' name='reason' /></p><br/>
                        <p><input type='hidden' name='bundlereference' id='Username' value='" . $x['Reference'] . "' /></p>
                        <input type='submit' name ='add'/>
                    </form>
                </table>";   
} else {
    $content .= "<h3>Something has gone wrong</h3>
                <br>
                <a href='index.php?location=" . $x['Description'] . "'> Return to Previous Page </a> 
                ";
}

$template->SetTag("content", $content);
echo $template->Display();
```

Comment: The first one doesn't matter because PHP is weak-typed.

Comment: Ive tried adding your changes, still doesnt seem to work. If i echo the sql and enter the data manually it works. So odd. I'm pretty beginner to php. thanks for your help

Comment: ok, get rid of the return and then underneath mysql_query add the following: echo mysql_errno($this->conn) . ": " . mysql_error($this->conn) . "\n";

Comment: the only thing I can imagine is wrong now is that DB_DATABASE_NAME is either not set or wrong, the line of code I gave you above will let you know.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the code needed to debug any error.

Comment: ok, replace echo mysql_errno($this->conn) . ": " . mysql_error($this->conn); with die(mysql_error()); as a catch everything and after public function UpdateReason($reason, $bundlereference) { put the following (on a new line): error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

Comment: still no luck im afraid, when i press submit it hits the else statement after it.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you're now hitting the "Something has gone wrong" section of your code? If so that's because in your for action you're not specifying the reference again and so if($_GET{'reference']) is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Can I advise you break this down by first checking what mysql_query returns. It maybe that this particular variable is defined incorrectly. Also remember add quotes to the values in your query.